# Python is skipping instructions

Tags: python, sublimetext2, anaconda, interpreter

I have encountered a very weird problem.

From the tests that I have conducted, I have reached the conclusion that python is skipping instructions. (There seems to be a problem in the interpreter)

This is the part of the code where I am facing the issue:-

```
def foo():
    status_packet = some_fn()
    print("status_packet recvd:- "+str(status_packet))  #PRINT INSTRUCTION
    if(status_packet == False) :
        do_something()
    elif(status_packet == True):
        print("True packet received")                   #PRINT INSTRUCTION
        return True
    else:
        error = status_packet_handling.check_for_error(status_packet)
        if(error == False):
            print("false error")                        #PRINT INSTRUCTION
            return status_packet
print(foo())                                            #PRINT INSTRUCTION
print("okay")                                           #PRINT INSTRUCTION
print("close other open ports")                         #PRINT INSTRUCTION
print("ok_1234")                                        #PRINT INSTRUCTION
sys.exit(1)
```

The expected output is something like:-

```
status_packet recvd:- True
True packet received
okay
close other open ports
ok_1234
[Finished in 10.1s]
```

But I am getting the output as:-

```
status_packet recvd:- True

ok_1234
[Finished in 10.1s]
```

I am using **Python 2.7.10 ; Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)** and building using **Sublime Text 3**

I have tried adding print functions and other functions to see if my flow is correct. It is the print instructions which are getting skipped.

What can I do to identify and solve this problem?

**EDIT:-**
The important part is the print instructions being skipped.
**A simplified version** of this would be:-

```
def foo():
    print("foo called")
    return "foo_string"
print(foo())
print("print_statement 1")
print("print_statement 2")
print("print_statement 3")
```

Output observed:-

```
foo called

print_statement 3
```

**EDIT 2:-**
I think I need to mention that I am using a multi module scenario and I am passing modules via functions.
This is a **more complicated version:-**

*a.py*

```
import b
import c
c.function1(b)
import sys
sys.exit(1)
```

*b.py*

```
import e
import f

def function2():
    returned_value = e.some_function()
    print("returned_value = "+str(returned_value))
    return returned_value
```

*c.py*

```
def function1(b_module):
    print(b_module.function2())
    print("print_statement_1")
    print("print_statement_2")
    print("print_statement_3")
```

*OUTPUT:-*

```
returned_value = True

print_statement_3
```

Comment: What does `type(status_packet)` return?  Are you comparing a string to a bool?

Comment: Looks from the flow of foo() that it returns several different things - the value of status_packet, or True, or nothing. Why don't you at least put a print in every possible exit showing what it is returning? Also just in case there is more than one print statement that could print e.g. True, put an extra unique identifier in each print e.g. `print "#1",status_packet`

Comment: @g.d.d.c It returns True, False or a string. So yes I am comparing a string to a bool. But it works in python right?

Comment: @barny It is returning True in this scenario. but the important part is that it is skipping the next two lines of print.

Comment: The most common mistakes programmers make are when they assume they understand the behaviour of what they have written but then can't understand why it behaves like it does... Is the `return_status_packet` at the correct indent?

Comment: What if status_packet has the string value "True", for example - which flow through foo() is being followed?

Comment: Is the above code running in a thread where exceptions aren't reported?

Comment: Extraordinary claims (a bug in the Python interpreter) require extraordinary proof. Provide an [SCCCE](http://sscce.org/) which reproduces the problem. As it stands now, no one can tell what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: @barny Checked indentation ; rewrote that part of code ; string value will be a status packet like:- "\xff\xff\x02\xfb\x00" ; Most importantly it was working well till today. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: I think you should dummy out some of the functions and create a _complete_ simplified piece of code which shows the same error so that e.g. I could run the code to reproduce (or not) the error. Chances are it is the code you aren't showing which is actually causing the strange behaviour, somehow. E.g. some_fn(), do_something(), etc - do they have some unforeseen side-effects? Maybe one of these is modifying status_packet?

Comment: @Dark Falcon and barny:  It will include many lines of code if i make it self contained. Is there something else I can try out (maybe something other than the print function to help me understand the flow)

Comment: No. Copy your code. Begin removing chunks of it until either it is small enough or you can no longer reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is going on in `some_fn` and where are you printing this? The console? On Windows or Linux or what? The reason I'm asking is that it's hard to imagine any reason whatsoever that Python would just randomly jump over two module-level statements. Python 2.7 has been out for six years and it seems this has never happened to anyone but you.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist It has left me bewildered too. I am using Sublime Text 3 as my code editor and running python using the build command. There has to be some issue elsewhere which I cannot locate

Comment: Can we rule out sublime as a possible source of error? Run it from the command line?

Comment: When I run your EDIT code from the command line using python 2.7, I get output as expected `foo called
foo_string
print_statement 1
print_statement 2
print_statement 3`  You run that code from the commandline and see what you get.

Comment: @barny I have reverted back to a working code so I have lost the error. I think my best guess would be something related to different threads as u pointed out. And one of the subprocesses in these threads may have caused the program to end..the problem is solved for now. But I can always roll back to my previous commit and try out different stuff  to identify the error for future users. So suggestions are welcome.